# discord.py error when forwarding embeds to another channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an issue about discord.py. I have a code for forwarding embed messages to another discord channel, but it gives me an error. How can I solve it?

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 301, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\newBodyguard\d2d.py", line 27, in on_message
    await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1061, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 302, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

```py
import discord
from discord import channel

USER_DISCORD_TOKEN = 'u3VulQw33THPGbPlx_aUHC.............'
channel1id = 12844415 #source channel 
channel2id = 71038106 #target channel

async def on_ready():
    print("Copier is ready")

class MyClient(discord.Client):
   
        
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    
    async def on_message(self, message):
        try:
            serverName = message.guild.name
            channelId = message.channel.id
            channelName = message.channel.name
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        print(f"Server: {serverName}, Channel: {channelName}")
        if message.channel.id == channel1id:
            channeltosend = client.get_channel(channel2id)
            await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])
            print(message)
            print('****************')
            print(message.embeds)
       
               
client = MyClient()
client.run(USER_DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

edit: i added two lines but still same error (discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message). can anyone share full code. am i wrong?

```
import discord
from discord import channel

USER_DISCORD_TOKEN = 'TOKEN HERE'
channel1id = 823473 #source
channel2id = 910981 #dest

async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

class MyClient(discord.Client):
   
        
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    
    async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        serverName = message.guild.name
        channelId = message.channel.id
        channelName = message.channel.name
        print(f"Server: {serverName}, Channel: {channelName}")
        if message.channel.id == channel1id:
            channeltosend = client.get_channel(channel2id)
            await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])
            print(message)
            print('****************')
            print(message.embeds)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    print(f"Server: {serverName}, Channel: {channelName}")
       
               
client = MyClient()
client.run(USER_DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Edit 1: sent message is "@deleted role"

async def on_ready():
print("Bot is ready")

class MyClient(discord.Client):

```
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as', self.user)

async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        serverName = message.guild.name
        channelId = message.channel.id
        channelName = message.channel.name
        print(f"Server: {serverName}, Channel: {channelName}")
        if message.channel.id == channel1id:
            channeltosend = client.get_channel(channel2id)
            await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])
            print(message)
            print('****************')
            print(message.embeds)
    except discord.errors.HTTPException:
        pass
    print(f"Server: {serverName}, Channel: {channelName}")
```

client = MyClient()
client.run(USER_DISCORD_TOKEN)

Answer (score 1):

The "Cannot send an empty message" error happens because the bot tries to send a message with empty content and no embed (presumably because there was a message in the source channel that had neither, e.g. a message with just an image - those go to `message.attachments`, not to `message.content`)

---

The easiest way to get around this is to simply `try: ... except` your `await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])` call and ignore/log the error, but you may want to copy any attachments to the target channel anyways, so perhaps you should check for attachments and copy them over instead. You can achieve that by using [`to_file()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment.to_file) on the attachment and then submit that to the `file`-parameter of `channeltosend.send` (or `files` and a list of attachments if there are multiple) something like:

```py
files = [await attachment.to_file() for attachment in message.attachments]
...
await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0], files=files)
```

Comment: not worked for me. i just want copy all messages (text and embed messages in channel) from a channel to another channel. if you have like this code can you share it.?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "not worked for me"? What did you change? What happened?

Comment: python code editted. but still error

Comment: I assume this would still fail for stickers and similar items, though I have not tested that. Just wrap your `channeltosend.send` message in a `try: ... except:` statement and deal with the empty messages in the `except` clause

Comment: i changed but still error.

Comment: Please edit your original question to show your changes. With a try except in place, the error can't be raised unless you explicitly do it

Comment: second code editted.

Comment: You're only catching `AttributeError`s. Any other errors (such as your `discord.errors.HTTPException` will still raise. Change the except clause to `(AttributeError, discord.errors.HTTPException)` and the error will be caught and ignored as well

Comment: code editted. and the sent message is only @deleted role.

Comment: That is now an entirely new question. Please go ahead and make a new post about the new issue, we've deteriorated far from what the original issue was :-)

Comment: Umm no it is not @LukasThaler, actually please read my answer. My solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what the value of the variable `message.embeds[0]` is? If `message.embeds[0]` is `None` (NoneType), then it is very possible that it is the reasoning behind your issue. Note these things:

1. If you are sending an embed, you do NOT need to send a message
2. When you do send an embed you need AT LEAST a title OR a description. That is the ABSELOUTE MINIMUM.

Try see the value of `message.embeds[0]`. Also, I noticed something as I was doing testing for you. [image]

You can see that the first object is from `await channel.send(embed=embed)`, but the second one is from `await channel.send(message.embeds[0])`. Have you tried manually adding the arguments of the `discord.Embed` object to another embed? Like:

```
await channel.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = message.embeds[0].title,
        description = message.embeds[0].description,
        # etc.
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share the full code? I couldn't do it. my messages embeds are: description, title, color and url.

example message:

{'color': 65280, 'type': 'rich', 'description': 'UPTO\n\n**7.69% \n\n', 'url': 'https://www.kucoin.com/price/ADX', 'title': 'ADX'}